# Calculating the angle for a path between two nodes in a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I want to (programatically) draw an edge between two nodes in a graph, starting on the outside of the nodes. Below is an illustration of what I'm (poorly) trying to describe:

[image]

I have the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the two nodes. I'm assuming I need to calculate the angle $a$ between the nodes as illustrated in the following figure (though I'm not sure, it's been a while since I mathed.)

[image]

Any help would be **greatly appreciated** :-)

Comment: Typically a graphing utility would just let you declare the coordinates of the two points and then draw the line between them.

Comment: @alex.jordan I'm doing this programatically using javascript without a library (for the challenge I guess as well as trying to understand the mathematics behind it all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got this thing working, using the ideas presented by @recursiverecursion.

This is how I did it (I chose R=15 as the nodes have a radii of 10, which would ensure that the lines started from a point *outside* the nodes, as per my figure.

$$
  \theta = arctan(\frac{y_0-y_1}{x_0-x_1})\\
\Delta x = R * cos(\theta)\\
\Delta y = R * sin(\theta)\\
$$

Then I drew a line from $(x_o + \Delta x, y_0-\Delta y)$ to $(x_1 - \Delta x, y_1+\Delta y)$. Worked splendidly :-)

Answer (score 0):

The equation for the slope of a line is:

```
       m = (y0 - y1)/(x0 - x1)
```

The equation of a line in point-slope form is:

```
       (y - y0) = m*(x - x0)
```

Solving for y gives:

```
       y = m*(x - x0) + y0
```

Now, all you have to do is compute the y that goes best (rounding off) with each x, this gives you many (x,y) coordinate pairs.  Each pair corresponds to a pixel that you can colour by calling some subroutine function designed for that purpose.  That is, at least, one way to do it.  A vertical line would need to be handled specially, since its slope is undefined.

Comment: Cheers! What would I use as *m* in the calculations?

Comment: In your question you said, "I have the (x,y) coordinates of the two nodes."  So you have (x0,y0) and (x1,y1).  Just use these values in the equation that I gave for the slope m of a line ;-)

Comment: You're quite right, sorry. :p

Answer (score 0):

(I assume the radius for both circles is $r$, but it's easy to adapt the following if not.)

Similar triangles work well in these situations:

Let the centers of the two circles be $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.
Then the vector joining the centers is $\langle \Delta x, \Delta y \rangle$, where $\Delta x = x_2-x_1$, and $\Delta y = y_2-y_1$.

Point on circle 1 will be $r$ distance away from its center, so there is some scaling factor $a$ for the vector such that $a \cdot \sqrt{{\Delta x}^2 + {\Delta y}^2} = r$. After you have solved for $a$, then the point on circle 1 along the segment will have coordinates $(x_1 + a \cdot \Delta x, y_1 + a \cdot \Delta y)$.

Similarly, the point on circle 2 will have coordinates $(x_2 - a \cdot \Delta x, y_2 - a \cdot \Delta y)$. (Note that we use the same value of $a$ because the radii are the same, if the radii are different, then just scale accordingly: $a_2 = a_1 * r_2 / r_1$.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand how (Δx, Δy) can be a vector and not a point?

Comment: @Nicolay - that is why I used the angle-bracket notation. $\langle \Delta x, \Delta y \rangle$ denotes the vector with $\Delta x$ displacement in the $x$-direction and $\Delta y$ displacement in the $y$-direction, and specifically speaking has no "head" or "tail". $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$ is just a point in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I understand you question correctly, I think this will do the trick. As others have stated, the slope of this line would be $\frac{y_0-y_1}{x_0-x_1}$. Now to find the angle that you are describing, you would have to take this inverse tangent of the slope of the line, that is $\displaystyle{\arctan(\frac{y_0-y_1}{x_0-x_1})}$. If you look at your circle, then look up the definition of the arctangent function, I think you'll see why this works. Let's do a simple example:

If one of the nodes was at the origin, and the other was at $(1,0)$. From the formula, we have $\theta = \arctan(1) = 45^\circ$. As long as you know the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the nodes, you can employ this formula.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I go about using the θ to find the coordinates for the point at which to start the line? (outside of the node)